# Unexpected result in mongodb query with regular expression

Tags: regex, mongodb

The first query below shows the full content of the collection and the following three queries return one item as expected.

Why does the last query return two items?

```
> db.log.find()
{ "_id" : 123, "user" : "stefano" }
{ "_id" : 456, "user" : "franco" }
> db.log.find({'user':/st/})
{ "_id" : 123, "user" : "stefano" }
> db.log.find({'user':/fr/})
{ "_id" : 456, "user" : "franco" }
> db.log.find({'user':/st*/})
{ "_id" : 123, "user" : "stefano" }
> db.log.find({'user':/fr*/})
{ "_id" : 123, "user" : "stefano" }
{ "_id" : 456, "user" : "franco" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in Regex the `*` is a quantifier (matches between zero and unlimited times). So the `/fr*/` regex matches `f` literally and a `r` zero or unlimited times. (https://regex101.com/r/M8h249/1)

If you would like to create a regex which matches like a "starts with" then you can use the following: `/^fr/`.